# iOS 11 tableView layer bug

Tags: uitableview, ios11

I have a tableview that worked fine up to iOS10.  With iOS 11 adding a sublayer using

```
tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

in viewDidLoad causes the cell contents to not appear.  The tableview appears normal however in the view debugger.  This is what led me to suspect the layers because the view debugger does not render layers (afaik).

I don't know if this is a bug in the iOS 11 TableView. I know not really a question but I'm interested in any comments you might have.

Comment: Same here. Just started investigating.